# Keeping copies of the X log file on Debian

Tags: debian, x11, logrotate

I recently tried to replace my Nvidia driver with the Nouveau driver for my Nvidia card, (see [Switching from Nvidia proprietary driver to Nouveau driver for Nvidia card on Debian wheezy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/120970/edit)).

Unfortunately, this attempt crashed and burned, so I aborted it. However, after I booted back into my customary configuration, and the smoke cleared, I discovered something I knew already, that Debian only keeps one copy of the X server logs around, namely `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Therefore the log of my ill-fated attempt to switch to Nouveau had been lost.

So, my question is, how can I change Debian's configuration to keep old copies of the X log file?:

I thought this kind of logic was handled by logrotate, but `/etc/logrotate.conf`
and `/etc/logrotate.d/` don't have any specific logic about this, that I can see. Is it just a matter of adding something there? If so, I wonder why it isn't there already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X's logging behavior is:

1. If there is a `/var/log/Xorg.DISPLAY.log`, rename it to `/var/log/Xorg.DISPLAY.log.old`, overwriting any file that might be there.
2. Open `/var/log/Xorg.DISPLAY.log`, and begin logging to it.

Unfortunately, this isn't configurable, except in the sense all open-source software is: you could change the source code and recompile. It's in the `xserver-xorg` source package, grep for `LogInit` to find the right spots.

That said, you could find a way to preserve old logs. For example, `kdm` has several scripts in /etc/kde4/kdm that it runs as root before showing the login screen; you could add a `savelog` command to save the `.old` file. `gdm` presumably has similar.

Or you could use `dpkg-divert` on `/usr/bin/X` and put a script there that calls `savelog` on the non-old file and then exec's the real X. You could also just change the path your display manager (kdm, gdm) uses to run X to that script, and not divert X.

Comment: great ansower! I am curious that the logrotate still cannot handle Xorg log till now? I saw bunch of feature request there date back to 2010.

Comment: The Xorg command has an option to specify the log file: -logfile <filename>, so why can't that be used?