# xorg: lost screen resolution after Debian/Jessie upgrade

Tags: debian, xorg

After update/upgrade within Debian/Jessie (affecting some 50 packages) and a reboot (after an uptime of about a month), the full resolution 2560x1440 of my Dell U2713HM has gone. xrandr is listing at most 1920x1200.

Given the long history of my installation, I tried a radical cure, purging all xorg related packages, and reinstalling them. No effect, still limited to 1920x1200.

Then I tried

```
~$ cvt 2560 1440
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --addmode HDMI1 2560x1440
~$ xrandr  --output  HDMI1 --mode 2560x1440
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

The only trace of this in `Xorg.0.log` is the following:

```
[  3263.882] (II) intel(0): Allocated new frame buffer 2560x1440 stride 10240, tiled
[  3264.048] (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument
[  3264.080] (II) intel(0): Allocated new frame buffer 1920x1200 stride 7680, tiled
```

According to `lspci -v`, my video device is the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions Device 11e7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Since I installed the full `xorg` dependency package, missing drivers is not a likely explanation.

How to proceed?

Comment: Now also posted at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5148773#post5148773.

Comment: Did you save a copy of the original X logs? You could try comparing them. Also, putting a full copy of your current X logs somewhere (in the question if not too large) might be useful. One obvious is what range of resolutions does the driver currently recognize as valid. Also, asking on the xorg mailing lists might be more effective than here.

Comment: Range of resolutions does the driver currently recognize as valid: from 1920x1200, 1600x1200, 1680x1050 down to 720x400.

Comment: Thank you, @Faheem. I now went to the xorg mailing list.

Comment: I looked at your link. You don't have the log for the previous version of your X server, when it was running  2560x1440?

Comment: This is all I have. While xdm.log.3 of March is from when the system booted into 2560x1440, there is no corresponding Xorg.<n>.log.

Comment: X only keeps one previous log. The previous log is `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121050/4671 If that is from your previous config, it would be useful for debugging.

Comment: `Xorg.0.log.old` is from the same day as `Xorg.0.log`. No way to get back to pre-change log.

Comment: Ok. I hope the xorg people can help you. It must be frustrating losing resolution like that. One question, was your previous installation (with the higher resolution) with wheezy, or an earlier version of jessie? This is worth being clear about, I think.

Comment: It happened through an update within Jessie. Or through deinstallation of some package during one month of uptime.

Comment: Ok. That may make things harder to track down. In theory the xorg folks should be able to tell you what resolutions are supported with your card and that driver. If you get a solution, please update here. You can answer your own question and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: This thread https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179120 indicates some recently introduced problem with the Intel driver.

Comment: Did the xorg people have anything to say about this? This does look like a bug. I suggest that if this has not already been reported as a bug, you report it. If there is already a bug report, you can add your report to that. And add the link to the bug report here, either way. And mention the arch linux thread in the bug report.

Comment: On second thoughts, based on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1400815#p1400815 (good detective work) it looks like this may have been a deliberate change. You could in any case bring it up with the relevant people (you could email the people mentioned in the patch directly - they might reply). You also have the option, like frax, of patching your kernel, though that would be a burden in the long term.

Comment: Also, I suggest either putting that information from the link either in your question, or maybe better in an answer. That is useful and relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179120 indicates some recently introduced problem with the Intel driver (see also https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75345).

As was to be expected from that discussion, the problem only occurs with DVI cable. After switching to a DisplayPort cable, my full resolution was back.